# Test NextJS API middleware with Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jestjs, next.js

I have an API route with middleware setup in NextJS like so:

**/src/middleware/validateData/index.ts**

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import schema from './schema';

type Handler = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => void;

export default (handler: Handler) => {
  return (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    const { error } = schema.validate(req.body, { abortEarly: false });
    if (error) res.status(400).send(error);
    else handler(req, res);
  };
};
```

**/src/api/foo.ts**

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

import validateData from '../../middleware/validateData';

const foo = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  res.send('It works!');
};

export default validateData(foo);
```

The schema reference is a `@hapi/joi` schema to validate the `req.body` data and I haven't included it because I don't think it's relevant to the question.

I'm wondering how I can unit test the middleware on it's own? This is about as far as I got:

**/src/middleware/validateData/index.test.ts**

```
import validateData from './validateData';

describe('validateData', () => {
  const mockHandler = jest.fn();

  const mockReq = {
    body: '',
  };

  const mockRes = {
    send: jest.fn(),
  };

  it('responds with error', () => {
    validateData(mockHandler)(mockReq, mockRes);
    expect(mockRes.send).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

But with this technique I firstly get type errors that `mockReq` and `mockRes` are missing properties (so I guess I need to mock those correctly but not sure how), and secondly the test fails because `res.send` is not called despite invalid body data being passed.

Anyone know how to mock and test this correctly?

I feel like my approach is totally wrong because I want to inspect the entire response (status code, specific message received and so on). Is the only approach to spin up a mock server and actually mock an api call or something?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: You may need to cast type as `unknown` first and then as `NextApiRequest` or `NextApiResponse` type. This works for me. e.g. `as unknown as NextApiRequest`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
import handler from "@pages/api/clients";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { Client } from "@interfaces/client";

const mockedJson = jest.fn();

/** Mocked response object */
const mockedRes: jest.Mocked<NextApiResponse> = {
  status: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ json: mockedJson }),
} as unknown as jest.Mocked<NextApiResponse>;

const clientList: Client[] = [
 ...
];

describe("GET /api/clients", () => {
  it("should return a list of clients", () => {
    const req: NextApiRequest = {
      url: "/api/clients",
    } as NextApiRequest;
    handler(req, mockedRes);
    expect(mockedRes.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200);
    expect(mockedJson).toHaveBeenCalledWith(clientList);
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, however this doesn't work for me, because `res.status` returns the `res` object.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working version:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import handler from 'src/pages/api/change-password.api';

let req: NextApiRequest;
const res: jest.Mocked<NextApiResponse> = {
  status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  json: jest.fn(),
} as unknown as jest.Mocked<NextApiResponse>;

describe('API change password', () => {
  it('should return', async () => {
    await handler(req, res);
    expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200);
    expect(res.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name: 'Hello' });
  });
});
```

This is because `NextApiResponse` has this type:

```
export declare type NextApiResponse<T = any> = ServerResponse & {
    send: Send<T>;
    json: Send<T>;
    status: (statusCode: number) => NextApiResponse<T>;
    ...
}
```

And here is the handler file 'src/pages/api/change-password.api':

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse): Promise<unknown> {
  return res.status(200).json({ name: 'Hello' });
}

export default handler;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`next-test-api-route-handler`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-test-api-route-handler) is a package (disclaimer: I created!) that simplifies writing unit tests for Next API routes. It uses [`test-listen`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/test-listen) under the hood to generate real HTTP responses. For example:

```
import validateData from './validateData';
import { testApiHandler } from 'next-test-api-route-handler';

describe('validateData', () => {
  it('responds with error', async () => {
    await testApiHandler({
      handler: validateData((_, res) => res.send('It works!')),
      test: async ({ fetch }) => {
        // Returns a real ServerResponse instance
        const res = await fetch();
        // Hence, res.status == 200 if send(...) was called above
        expect(res.status).toBe(200);
        // We can even inspect the data that was returned
        expect(await res.text()).toBe('It works!');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This way, you can also directly examine the fetched response object in your tests. Better, your API route handlers will function *identically to how they would in Next.js* since they're passed actual [NextApiRequest and NextApiResponse](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript#api-routes) instances instead of TypeScript types or mocks.

More examples can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/Xunnamius/next-test-api-route-handler#real-world-examples).